# multiply and sum arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Im trying to calculate my own distance with numpy array by adding a weight to each sum in euclidean distance, for example:

```
a = ((1, 2, 3))
b = ((4, 5, 6))
distance = np.sum((a-b)**2)
```

but what I want is set my distance as:

```
a = ((1, 2, 3))
b = ((4, 5, 6))
w = ((0.2, 0,3, 0,5))
distance = 0.2*((1-4)**2) + 0.3*((2-5)**2) + 0.5*((3-6)**2)
```

is it any form of do this with numpy without iterate over echa vector and do this manually?

Comment: `a = ((1, 2, 3))` etc. are not proper numpy arrays. Could you add a bit more representative of the actual data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're halfway there:

```
a = np.array([[1., 2, 3]])
b = np.array([[4., 5, 6]])
w = np.array([[0.2, 0.3, 0.5]])

result = float(np.dot((a - b)**2, w.T))
```

So, you simply multiply a row-vector `(a - b)**2` by a column-vector `w.T` to get the number you want.

Please note that you'll have to make sure the arrays' dimensions match.

Comment: I just try it out, but i'm geting the following error:
 `ValueError: shapes (4,) and (3,) not aligned: 4 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)`

and I'm shure that dimensions match.

Comment: @rafaelleru, please copy & paste my code into your Python console and check the arrays' dimensions. Linear algebra only works with proper dimensions. BTW, there are typos in your code in initialization of `w`: there should be decimal points `.` instead of commas `,` in some places, so make sure they didn't slip into your actual code.